# Getting the assembly a control is being used in, from a custom UITypeEditor, at design time

Tags: uitypeeditor

Although there are many threads dealing with similar questions I couldn't find any that cover this case.

I have a main app that references a class library. In the class library is a control with a property that must be populated with a form name from a drop-down of forms available in the main app - NOT the class library.

I've discovered that, inside of the UITypeEditor code,

```
Control owner = context.Instance as Control;
```

gives me a reference to the control for which the property value is required. But getting a reference to the proper assembly (the main app, not the library the control is in) so that I can list the available form names in a drop down has proved difficult.

`owner.GetType().Assembly.ToString()` -- gives me the class library name, not the main app

`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString()` --- gives me the class library name

`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().ToString()` --- gives me System.Windows.Forms

There is no route I can find to getting the assembly of the form onto which I'm placing the control which has the property with  custom editor that needs that assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but it is easily answered if one understands the mechanisms employed in writing basic designer code.  There are three articles that I recommend reading to gain a working knowledge of the subject.

1. Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features; [MSDN Magazine, April 2003](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineApril2003en-us.chm)
2. Building Windows Forms Controls and Components with Rich Design-Time Features, Part 2; [MSDN Magazine, May 2003](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineMay2003en-us.chm)
3. Tailor Your Application by Building a Custom Forms Designer with .NET; [MSDN Magazine, December 2004](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineDecember2004en-us.chm)

Note:  The above links are to compiled HTML help files.  Remember to unblock the content using the file's properties dialog.

[image]

To obtain a reference to the `Assembly` that contains the `Form` with the `Control` being manipulated on the design surface, you need to obtain a reference to the [IDesignerHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.idesignerhost(v=vs.110).aspx) service from the `IServiceProvider` instance "provider" that is passed the `EditValue` method.  IDesignerHost exposes the property `RootComponentClassName` that will be the fully qualified name of the base component class which in this case is the containing form.  With this name you can obtain a `Type` instance using the `IDesignerHost.GetType` method.  Note that `GetType` may return a null value if the project has not been "built" since adding the form to the project.

**C# Example Snippet For UITypeEditor**

```
public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
    IDesignerHost host = provider.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
    string typName = host.RootComponentClassName;
    Type typ = host.GetType(typName);
    Assembly asm = null;
    if (typ == null)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please build project before attempting to set this property");
        return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
        }
    else
        {
        asm = typ.Assembly;    
        }
    // ... remaining code

    return base.EditValue(context, provider, value);
    }
```

**VB Example Snippet For UITypeEditor**

```
Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, provider As IServiceProvider, value As Object) As Object
    Dim host As IDesignerHost = TryCast(provider.GetService(GetType(IDesignerHost)), IDesignerHost)
    Dim typName As String = host.RootComponentClassName
    Dim typ As Type = host.GetType(typName)
    Dim asm As Assembly
    If typ Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please build project before attempting to set this property")
        Return MyBase.EditValue(context, provider, value)
    Else
        asm = typ.Assembly
    End If
    ' ... remaining code

    Return MyBase.EditValue(context, provider, value)
End Function
```